# Ionic 4 calling the generated tabs outlet

Tags: angular, tabs, router-outlet, ionic4

I installed the RC version of Ionic 4.

```
npm i -g ionic@rc
ionic start MyApp
```

Choose the template with tabs.

After the generation, I make a new page:

```
ionic g page welcome
```

From the home page, call the `WelcomePage`

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-title>Home</ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
  The world is your oyster.
  <p>If you get lost, the <a target="_blank" href="https://ionicframework.com/docs">docs</a> will be your guide.</p>
  <ion-button href='/welcome'>GoToWelcome</ion-button>
</ion-content>
```

From the `WelcomePage`, call the `HomePage` (it is an outlet of tabs)

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-title>welcome</ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
  <ion-button href='/tabs/(home:home)'>GoToHome</ion-button>
</ion-content>
```

This is the **app-routing.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

const routes: Routes = [ 
  { path: '', loadChildren: './pages/tabs/tabs.module#TabsPageModule' },
  { path: 'welcome', loadChildren: './pages/welcome/welcome.module#WelcomePageModule' }
];
@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

Let's test it:
`ionic serve`

After I click on the button `GoToWelcome` and click on the `GoToHome`. The tabs button (about, contact...) does not work anymore. Do calling outlet is different?